What is responsible generating rows in mat-table?
Even though Angular Material tables are easy to use, it's not clear to me how it actually works.
<table mat-table [dataSource]="myData">
    // cell definition ...

    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row,columns: myColumns"></tr>

</table>

Which of those directives is responsible for actually generating the rows? Is there a hidden *ngFor directive? How does mat-row know about the dataSource input or how does mat-table know about mat-row?
All I tried is to remove the mat-row statement and the rows were not rendered anymore. But this doesn't really show which of those directives is responsible for creating the rows.
